# Git clone: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: git, https, network-protocols

I got an error message showing `Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`
when I try to clone a repo on my PC, which the OS is windows 7.

I have searched on google and here and saw some similar questions asked, but I did not find a clear solution on how to fix this. I am quite new to programming, and it is my first time using Git, please help.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Did it work before? What command do you use to clone?

Comment: No, the command I use is: git clone https://github.com/username/Spoon-Knife.git

Answer (score 1):

For https support, libcurl must be compiled with libssl support and then installed.